# EFCore 3.1 sum column values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've read other questions and forums to find the right solution but they seem to not work in my case probably because they are an older version of EF. The other answers typically state that `decimal? data = db.Products.Sum(p => p.Cost);` will work but I just get the following error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet.Sum(p => p.Cost)' could not be translated.

So instead I run `decimal? data = db.Products.Select(p => p.Cost).AsEnumerable().Sum();`
But creating an enumerable will return all rows in the table an take much longer than necessary so what is the correct way to execute `Select Sum(Cost) from products;`

Comment: are tried this one: ``(from product in db.Products select product.Cost).Sum();``

Comment: I am guessing Cost is a standard property? i.e. public decimal? Cost {get;set;}.

Comment: I have executed your query with .Net core 3.1 and EF 3.1.2. It runs properly :))